# Fluid dynamics of an object in motion in a liquid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram

How does the resultant force acting on an object moving vertically downwards in water compare with the resultant force acting on an object moving upwards in water?

Comment: Are  the two objects moving with the same constant velocity (but opposite in sign), or is the acceleration constant? Moreover: are you in an idealized situation in which the shape of the objects is irrelevant? Are you considering fluid viscosity and drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram shows in detail the forces on a body moving upward / downward in a fluid .
In fig a the body is sinking so weight is more than buoyant force so net force is downward .As the body moves downward the viscous force acts on it upward.Now if the body is a sphere the viscous force on the body is directly proportional to its velocity.

Viscous force on a sphere = $6\pi \eta r v$
where v=velocity   ,    $\eta$ = coefficient of viscosity   ,   r = radius of sphere

Now as the body accelerates downward the velocity increases so viscous force also increases and a time is reached when the upward viscous force becomes equal to net downward force.At this instant net force becomes zero on the sphere so net acceleration of the sphere is zero and velocity of the sphere becomes constant.Since velocity is constant viscous force is also constant and the body continues to move with this constant velocity forever.This velocity is called Terminal Velocity .To find it :

upward viscous force = net downward force.$$6 \pi \eta r v = mg - v' \rho g$$

Here v' is volume and v is velocity.

Substituting v'(volume)=$\frac43 \pi r^3$
and ,

mass (m) = v'$\times$density($\sigma$) = $\frac43 \pi r^3 \sigma$

Here $\sigma$ is density of solid.

Solving the above equation we get,
$$ v_{terminal}=\frac{2r^2(\sigma - \rho)g}{9 \eta}$$

This is the concept of Terminal velocity

In fig b the body moves upward  so weight is less than buoyant force so net force is upward .As the body moves upward the viscous force acts on it downward.As the body accelerates upward viscous force in downward direction increases with velocity and  a point is reached when the net force is zero and the body again achieves Terminal Velocity.

**NOTE : USING ABOVE FORMULA WE GET TERMINAL VELOCITY POSITIVE WHEN BODY IS SINKING (TERMINAL VELOCITY DOWNWARD) AND TERMINAL VELOCITY NEGATIVE WHEN BODY IS RISING (TERMINAL VELOCITY UPWARD) **
[image]